# How to cite a TED Talk with Youtube URL in MLA 8?

Tags: citations, citation-style

How do I do it? I've already googled the heck out of it but all the answers were incomplete.

The URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2tOp7OxyQ8

Comment: Note that youtube videos might be taken down, deleted (or even changed, not sure) at any time, so such a video would not be a good source. Can you find the video elsewhere, e.g. in some news archive, on some homepage where chances are high(er) that it will stay there untouched for quite some time? If not, can you get it on such a platform?

Comment: The professor specifically gave us a list of YouTube links in order to analyze the video. So, I guess I cannot do that.

Comment: Then why not ask said professor? If he wants youtube videos as sources, he should know how to cite them. Furthermore, you might add what exactly you are writing  - e.g. for a class work that no one will ever read after it is graded, it doesn't matter if the video might not be there anymore in a few years, while for a paper to be published, it might well be important.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold that's the case for any online resource which is why you add the date of when you accessed it.

Comment: TED Talks are generally available both on YouTube and on TED's own website. It may be easier to cite the latter.

Answer (score -2):

1. Write the name or username of the compiler. If the user indicates his or her real name, use it. Otherwise, use the compiler's username or screenname. If citing from YouTube's official channel, specify the username as "YouTube." Follow with a period.

> ```
> Doe, John.
> Sephora.
> YouTube.
> ```

2. Name the video. Put the title in quotation marks and follow it with a period. Capitalize the first letter of all major word (that is, anything that isn't an article, conjunction, preposition, or "to").

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012."

3. Specify the format of the citation. Indicate that you are citing an "Online video clip." Follow with a period.

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012." Online
>   video clip.

4. Indicate that the video came from YouTube. Even if the video was pulled from the official YouTube account, you still need to indicate that the video was pulled from YouTube. Italicize the website's name, and follow with a comma.

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012." Online video clip. YouTube,

5. List the posting date. Type out the date in day-month-year format. Conclude with a period.

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012." Online
>   video clip. YouTube, 21 December 2012.

6. State that the video came from the Web. This may seem redundant, but MLA format requires you to specify whether each source is electronic or print. Write "Web" and follow it with a period.

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012." Online
>   video clip. YouTube. 21 December 2012. Web.

7. Indicate the date you retrieved the video. Write this date out in day-month-year format. End with a final period.

> YouTube. "Top Searches on YouTube: August - November 2012." Online
>   video clip. YouTube, 21 December 2012. Web. 31 December 2012.

P.S: Source: WikiHow.

Comment: This does not look MLA 8